# page refresh - Hiding everything after click on submit

Tags: jquery

I have a jsp page with 3 sections. the first section always visible and it has 2 buttons and when user click first button then 2nd section is shown and 3rd sction hided same way if user click on another button then 3rd section will be shown and second section will be hided. The problem i am facing is when i click on submit button in 2nd or 3 rd section then page is refreshing and going back initial stage of hiding these 2 sections. I want to show that section after hitting 'submit' and page refresh. Here is my code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery('#content1').hide()
    // jQuery('#content2').hide()

    jQuery("#part3 :input").attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery("#part2 :input").attr("disabled", true);
    // $('#cselect').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");   
    jQuery('#part2').addClass("opc");
    jQuery('#part3').addClass("opc");

    jQuery('#FileUpload').live('click', function(event) {   
        jQuery("#part2 :input").attr("disabled", false);
        jQuery("#part3 :input").attr("disabled", true);
        // $('#cselect').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");        
        jQuery('#part2').removeClass("opc");
        jQuery('#part3').addClass("opc");

        // jQuery('#content1').show()
        // jQuery('#content2').hide()   
    });
    jQuery('#FillForm').live('click', function(event) {     
        jQuery("#part3 :input").attr("disabled", false);
        // $('#cselect').prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");     
        jQuery("#part2 :input").attr("disabled", true);
        jQuery('#part2').addClass("opc");
        jQuery('#part3').removeClass("opc");

        // jQuery('#content2').show()
        // jQuery('#content1').hide()
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you submit data with AJAX instead? No one likes page reloading.

Comment: What does your html look like? If you're using an actual submit button, you might want to add an e.preventDefault() function to your click event. I don't understand why you need the page refresh? No state can be saved (unless you're working with cookies, but that does not seem the right answer in this situation).

Comment: not going on ajax path..

Comment: I am submitting a form with data and once i click on submit this section of jquery is applying jQuery("#part3 :input").attr("disabled", true);
          jQuery("#part2 :input").attr("disabled", true);
    //  $('#cselect').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");   
          jQuery('#part2').addClass("opc");
          jQuery('#part3').addClass("opc");

Comment: Look at the code, if i am in  'file upload' or ' fill form' section then that section not need to be hided after clicking on submit so thats what i want